# Shimano 105 gear change won't stay tuned

Tags: shimano

A bike shop replaced my cassette, and chain on my 105. After about 70 km the shifting starts to deteriorate - slips,skips or noisy operation. This type of rapid deterioration occurs after every tune up. Best I can expect from the 105?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Bob. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best of the site. Regarding your question, no, even for Shimano that result is pretty poor. How old is the groupset, how many gears, and what is the derailleur length? What is the frame - is it flexible? And what's the front derailleur / chain ring setup?

Comment: You should expect better from 105, but we would need more information to suggest help strategy. However, any bike shop worthy of the name should be able to diagnose and fix the problem. One possibility - are your front rings worn?

Comment: Sounds like cable stretch to me - perfectly normal, and you use the barrel adjuster on the rear mech to take up the slack.

Answer (score 1):

Any named series shimano, sram, or campagnolo setup should work for thousands of miles/KM without much attention.

Where you are riding may be an especially dirty area or there could be moisture (puddles count as moisture!) that could be causing you an issue.  Also, your bike storage location could be causing water to enter your housings and causing problems.  And finally, if you routinely put your bike down on the drive side... that causes all sorts of difficulties.

Really need to know more about your issue, but poor shifting performance can be caused by:

- Cable/cable-housings that need to be cleaned, re-lubed, or replaced.
- dirty chain
- chain that needs to be lubed
- chain that needs to be replaced
- worn out cassette
- bent Rear Derailleur hangar(e.g. damaged)
- bent Rear Derailleur (e.g. damaged)
- worn out Jockey Pulley
- Rear wheel installed crooked (hard to do on most bikes, but non-vertical rear dropouts are susceptible to this, especially when a quick release is involved.)
- sometimes a 10spd chain used on an 8 speed cassette/chain-ring can cause issues (but not always) or a 9spd used on an 11spd, etc.

Firstly, I would check to see if your rear derailleur is in-plane with the cassette. If the RD is bent, the hangar is bent, or the jockey pulleys are worn it'll be very finicky to keep in adjustment.  (e.g. nearly impossible...)

Comment: Poor shifting is also generally experienced after break-in on a new cable.  Specifically after a tuneup, this would be the first thing I would expect/look for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you talk to the shop you took the bicycle to and find out what all the tune up entailed.  Degraded shifting performance after some riding is exactly what you would expect if the cable and/or housing has been replaced (on any quality of shifter).  Shifting cables are steel and will stretch after some initial use.  When they do, they become "untuned" and generally require a bit of additional tension.